# Custom Fields and new version of csvimporter aka API csv Importer

Tags: api, import, csv

I installed CiviCRM 5.41.0 and csvimporter 1.7.  My overall goal is to import data from csv files.  I created some custom fields, imported the standard fields using the standard importer and then moved to csvimporter to add the custom fields.

I had started this project with older versions of Civi and csvimporter. Csvimporter was working for me then.  With these new versions the screens are much better formatted - thanks to Eileen for those improvements. But I think there is something I do not understand.

On the first step, I pick  import CustomField in the "Entity to Import" but when I go to map the import fields in Step 2, I do not see my custom fields listed, rather, I see other choices related to fields. (See attached image) I think this means that I have picked the wrong "Entity to Import". The custom fields have been created for households and also individuals, but I do not see those choices in "Entity to Import" list.  Contacts seems to be the next best case, but also that gives me no joy.

I also do not see how to map the external ID although I did click the check box for "Allow Updating An Entity Using Unique Fields"

Obviously there is something changed in this new version of csvimporter that I do not understand.  Can you point me in the right direction?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I can't help on the csvimporter part as I am not using it but the `CustomField` entity is used for defining custom fields. It could be used if you want to create new custom fields from a csv file so it's not what you are looking for.

Instead, you should use the `Contact` entity which should have the custom fields you need.

If csvimporter doesn't work, you might want to simply use the standard CiviCRM importer for this which import csv just fine and support custom fields for contacts :

[image]

Comment: Agree that the description of the problem sounds like you are trying to import 'data for custom fields' not 'custom fields' themselves, and hence you should not need the csv extension. Perhaps Eric can clarify with some sample data that needs importing